# How to get the handlers for the applications within windows application c#?

Tags: windows, dll, command-line-arguments, citrix

I am having windows application A on my desktop. And from the application i am running application B which launch 3 different application but it is hosted on Citrix server and they are getting opened out side the application A. I want to get the handlers for that 3 diffrent applications so that i can tab those applciations in Application A.

Can anybody tell me how can i get the handlers for the applciations or any other way to identify the applications so that i can show them in Application A.

Any help is apprecited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d60f0793-cc92-48fb-b867-dd113dabcd5c/how-to-find-the-child-processes-associated-with-a-pid?forum=csharpgeneral (it kills children but you just have to enumerate them)

Comment: Thanks Adriano.. but i have changed my question little. That appliation B is hosted on server so how will i get the handlers ? Any help is appricated.. Thanks again

Comment: How can you "tab" remote processes on your application? Using WMI (Win32_Process class) you can gather them but it's all you can do (get information, not output)